# Using fabric8 API to check kubernetes cron jobs

Tags: java, kubernetes, ivy, fabric8

I'm trying to create a java test to check the status of cron jobs on a kubernetes, however I'm having trouble with the fabric8 imports.

I've tried

```
    import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.batch.Job;
    import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.batch.JobList;
```

However this throws an error. For some reason, java cannot resolve the 'batch' symbol. This tells me there is probably something missing in my ivy.xml dependencies.

I have the following dependencies already in my ivy.xml

```
    <dependency org="io.fabric8" name="kubernetes-client" rev="3.1.12"/>
    <dependency org="io.fabric8" name="kubernetes-api" rev="2.0.9"/>
    <dependency org="io.fabric8" name="kubernetes-model" rev="3.1.12"/>
```

Am I missing a dependency? Or is there another problem?

Comment: Could you please add your kubernetes version? Your k8-client version seems quite old. Why don't you try latest version v4.1.1?

Comment: `kubernetes-api` is deprecated. I won't recommend using it

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Could you please share your project if possible so that I can try reproducing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the dependencies were out of date.

The dependency for JobList wasn't added until several versions later. Apparently, nobody on our team has updated those dependencies in our ivy file for almost a year.

In other words, to avoid issues like this, one should always keep there dependencies up to date.